# External Hard Disk not recognised on USB 3 port

Tags: usb, hard-drive, usb-drive, external-hdd

I tried fdisk -l but it did not show the disk

> Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors Units: sectors
> of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
> 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical):
> 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096
> bytes Disklabel type: gpt Disk identifier:
> 69E1ACD8-C5EE-413A-9724-B98754DB0A02
>
> Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type /dev/sda1
> 2048     616447    614400   300M Windows recovery environment
> /dev/sda2      616448     821247    204800   100M EFI System /dev/sda3
> 821248    1083391    262144   128M Microsoft reserved /dev/sda4
> 1083392  627402293 626318902 298.7G Microsoft basic data /dev/sda5
> 627402752  629147647   1744896   852M Windows recovery environment
> /dev/sda6   629147648  991803696 362656049   173G Microsoft basic data
> /dev/sda7  1363150848 1953521663 590370816 281.5G Microsoft basic data
> /dev/sda8   991805440 1346512895 354707456 169.1G Linux filesystem
> /dev/sda9  1346512896 1363150847  16637952     8G Linux swap
>
> Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Next I tried lsusb, but it did not list the hard disk too.

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
>
> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
>
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

The issue is only occuring in USB3 port, but it is working in USB2 ports.

Comment: Have you tested the drive with other computers? Have you tested the port with other devices? It could be that the port is bad.

Comment: @PatrickNegus : the port is working OK when I connect my mobile as USB

Answer (score 0):

Use `dmesg` tool to see kernel "raw" messages about this disk.

If there is no ones maybe you have hardware problems:

- on this machine (with USB bus probably)
- with this disk

In this case the only way to check it is to use it on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I recently hooked up 4 drives using USB 3.0.
The drives were as follows:

- WD 2.5 Laptop SATA (160GB)
- SSD Drive (60GB)
- Hitachi 3.5 SATA (320GB)
- Seagate 3.5 SATA (2TB)

I used Sabient adapters, 2 non-powered for the first two drives and two powered for the 3.5's.

The Seagate (2TB) drive was giving me issues until I swapped the the two powered adapters.

I looked at the specs for the Seagate drive and realized it needed ideally 2.5 amps and figured that it was probably not getting sufficient to function properly. I swapped adapters with the Hitachi and it worked.

**My prediction is that your adapter is the source of the problem, not the USB port.**